# Тема для дипломного проекта

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста придумать тему для дипломного.
 Реализовывать буду на java. Желательно что-то для учебного заведения

Comment: Онлайн расписание - банально/занято/сложно реализуемо?

Comment: анализ причин побудивших робота томми убить себя об стену.

Comment: онлайн расписание - банально. да и есть уже на сайте

Comment: Подобные вопросы нужно обсуждать с дипломным руководителем, а не на форумах.

Comment: Распределение мест в студенческих общагах (по курсу, факультету, полу и т.д.).

Comment: нечто подобное приходило мне в голову - хочется что-то более интересное

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из данных по успеваемости и статистики отчислений, сделайте программу, которая будет считать с какой долей вероятности тот или иной ученик группы будет отчислен. Пишется всё очень просто, математика простая, ну и тема весёлая :))

Comment: пожалуй, руководитель дипломного не оценит

Comment: И что это за руководитель такой, что к нему проблематично подойти? Понимаете руководителю платят за каждого дипломника, либо же (в зависимости от страны), ему идет в плюс еще один защитившийся.
Придите со списком тем и обговорите, он сам вас наставит как надо, что бы не опозорится. А тему с прогнозированием отчисления вам предложили отличную, никакого юмора тут нет.